# using same ids on different pages cause of picture elements not rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a 6 page site and have finished the template for the navigation elements, the problem is, I just put the css & js into external files for the elements that will be the same on each page but now they aren't rendering on the original page or the new page, just showing white where there should be images.

Is this because I used id's on the elements instead of classes? 
I thought it wouldn't matter if the id's were on separate pages that's why I'm asking here as it could be something else.

Comment: No, it's not because of that. You can use the same IDs on different pages. The CSS/JavaScript code that "uses" those IDs, will find the corresponding elements no matter on what page they are.

Comment: Dunno why someone downvoted, it was a relevant question that hasn't been asked with an answer that may be useful to others in future.

Comment: It's been downvoted because they like to show they have voting rights. +1 just for negation.

Comment: @Jawad Thanks, I know it's an amateur question, but this site is for people of all skill levels so it really could be useful for a beginner somewhere down the line. Also, now I'm sure of what I thought I knew beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After putting the CSS & JS into external files Dreamweaver asked if I would like to update the links, I answered yes and it changed all background images in the external css file from (images/image.jpg) to (file:///images/image.jpg), I had to change them all back to the original path. Problem solved.

Comment: Your URLs start with `file://`? That won't work on a web-server.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas No, that was the problem - Dreamweaver changed the paths to that. I had to change them back, made answer more clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if id's are on sepereate pages.  You probably have a JS error somewhere in your migration.  Did you load the page with firebug/chromedevelopertools/iedevelopertools open and see if there is a JS error?

Comment: I tried that, it wasn't a js error, thanks for your input though. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` are not the problem. check that the relative path is still correct according to the css file. to me that seems to be the most probable mistake.

Comment: The same thing occured to me just moments before you posted this :) thanks